# Is $\pi = 3.14159...$ first-order definable in the reals?

Tags: real-numbers, first-order-logic, pi

Given first-order logic with equality and the real field $\mathbb{R} = (R, 0, 1, <, +, \cdot)$, is $\pi$ *first-order definable*?

By *first-order definable*, I mean a sentence of the form $\exists x \;\phi(x)$ such that $\pi$ is the only element in $R$ satisfying $\phi$.

Comment: I doubt it as $\pi$ is transcendental and cannot be expressed as the root of a polynomial.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bailey%E2%80%93Borwein%E2%80%93Plouffe_formula) would be helpful? If you could convert each binary digit into the actual value by multiplying by the appropriate power of two, and add all such values, you would get $\pi$. I don't know whether this could be stated as a first-order logic statement.

Comment: The conventional wording for your "pinpoint" would be to ask whether $\pi$ is _first-order definable_ in the structure $(\mathbb R,0,1,{<},{+},{\cdot})$.

Comment: @shardulc It cannot, in fact.

Comment: Depending on the fine details of the question, there is a cheat: if you've given me $R$ to use as constant symbols, then I can use $\phi(x) := (x = \pi)$. But the answer is "no" if $0$ and $1$ are the only constant symbols you give me.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, you cannot. Although $\pi$ has "reasonably concrete" definitions in terms of $+, \times, <$ (e.g. via infinite series), none of them can be made first-order. This follows, e.g., from the fact that:

- The algebraic reals form a real closed field.
- The theory of real closed fields is complete, and in fact if $F_1, F_2$ are real closed fields with $F_1\subseteq F_2$, then $F_1\preccurlyeq F_2$.
- $\pi$ is not algebraic.

Comment: In somewhat more detail, the second bullet point implies that any first-order statement true of $\mathbb{R}$ is also true of the real algebraic numbers, so if there were a first-order statement picking out $\pi$ the statement "$\pi$ exists" would be first-order, hence true of the real algebraic numbers, which would mean that $\pi$ is algebraic.