# What is the signficance and intended purpose of variable assignments in first order logic?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic

I have what might be a strange question. In so many words: what use is the notion of a variable assignment in first-order logic? Why *care* about variable assignments at all?

I'm not asking "what is a variable assignment?" I know what a variable assignment is: it's a function that maps from every variable in a (fragment of) a language to an element of the domain in the model for that language.

My question is: why should I care? When will this be useful? I'm not asking to be flippant. I feel like I can't fully understand what variable assignments are util I know what they could be used for and why (if at all) they are signficant. Here's why I'm struggling to see why they are.

- First, from what I understand, a variable assignment assigns a referent to a free variable. But overwhelmingly, I'll only ever be working with with sentences -- i.e. WFFs that contain no free variables.
- Second, it seems that I'm meant to think that a model $\mathfrak{M} = <D, I> $ or structure $\mathfrak{S} = <D, R_1 ... R_n, F_1 ... F_n>$ [this gets taught in different ways] is somehow incomplete or bad if it fails to provide a variable assignment for each variable in the (fragment of the) language we're working with. But why should I think this? After all, I'll almost never encounter a free variable, so I won't be concerned with the referent of the variable at all, and the whole point of variables is to substitute them, anyways. Why would I ever want a fixed assignment for a variable, given the high likelihood I'll be doing some substitution into it anyways?

Is the idea just that on the extremely low chance I encounter a free variable on its own or in an atomic WFF I'll need to know how to interpret it? That makes some sense, but it still conflcits with my intution that we shouldn't want any interpretation of variables at all. Why should I *want* it to be the case that, say, x = [____] at all? I'm inclined to think it's preferable to say that variables don't have referents, and consequently free variables and formulas containing free variables just fail to refer or don't have meaning. What am I missing?

OK. Sorry for the weird question. I'm just trying to figure out exactly what the significance of variable assignments is. I *must* be missing something.

Comment: Re: "What is a 'variable assignment?" In computer programming languages, the statement x=y is usually a command to move a copy of the data at the location assigned to the variable y to the location assigned to the variable x. It is not a symmetric relation. It is not logically equivalent to y=x. In a formal proof, however, the statement x=y means only that the symbols x and y are interchangeable in any statement including x=y itself. I think is would be misleading to call it an "assignment" of any kind.  In a formal proof, after all, x=y is logically equivalent to y=x.

Comment: You need variable assignments for recursively evaluating formulas by decomposing them into subformulas, where the variable will eventually be detached from its binding quantifier. $\forall x \phi(x)$ is true iff $\phi(x)$ is true for all possible values of $x$. But when we check the truth value of $\phi(x)$, what is $x$? This is what we need variable assignments for.

Comment: Variable assignments are relevant not only for free variables. We need variable assignments for bound variables too, because a quantifier is nothing but a loop over variable assignments.

Comment: How do you undertsand "It is red"? By pointing woth a finger to an object on your desk; this is "assigning" a reference to the pronoun "it". The same for the formula "x is red": we need a way to assign a reference (an object of the domain of the interpretation) to the variable "x".

Comment: Ah, wow. Thank you so much. I see that I was badly misunderstanding the issue. This clarifies it majorly. Thank you all for the help! To put it into words I'm more familiar with, I take it that ff we didn't have variable assignments, then the meaning of WFFs formulas with variables in first order logic wouldn't be compositional (and might not be determinable at all?). That indeed seems like a problem! Thanks for correcting me!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even though a sentence like $\forall x. P(x)$ is a closed formula, you need 'variable assignment' to express what validity in a model $M$ means. By definition, $M \models \forall x. P(x)$ means that for all assignments $\eta$ of $x$, $M \models_\eta P(x)$.

(Note that this is essentially the point the lemontree is making in a comment.)

Of course, if you really wanted, you could temporarily look at a new language structure, one in which there is an additional constant symbol that you're going to use to hold the semantics of $x$, and say that $M \models \forall x P(x)$ means that $M,a \models P(x)$ for all $a$. But that's just a way of writing down the variable assignment in a different way.

Answer (score 2):

Variable assignments are useful for *talking about parameters* and for *talking about definable sets*.

You can talk about parameters by using *additional constant symbols*, but definable sets are basically collections of variable assignments and I can't think of a reasonable way to talk about them without using a variable assignment or something similar.

Here's an example of a question that uses definable sets. This question is a little contrived.

Suppose we are interested in whether the function $\sin$ is definable in $(\mathbb{R}, 0, 1, +, -, *)$ in structures that satisfy $\text{Th}(\mathbb{R})$, i.e. [the real closed fields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_closed_field).

What does it mean for a function to be definable?

It means that the graph of the function is a definable set.

So, we want to know whether the set $\{ (x, y) : y = \sin(x) \}$ is equivalent to any sets of the form $\{ (x, y) : \varphi(x, y, \vec{p}) \}$ where $\varphi$ is a formula with vocabulary $(0, 1, +, -, *)$ and $\vec{p}$ is a collection of parameters in $\mathbb{R}$.

I don't have a full proof of this fact, but we can prove that $\sin$ is not 0-definable by noting that, if it were 0-definable, then $\pi$ would be 0-definable as the solution to $\sin(x) = 0$ between $3$ and $4$ and [$\pi$ is not 0-definable in real-closed fields](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1837981/is-pi-3-14159-first-order-definable-in-the-reals).